Find Template in django
My code is like below.
{% if request.path != '/login/' %}
      {% include "/hospital/templates/header.html" %}   
{% endif %}

I am getting error
TemplateDoesNotExist at /dashboard/
/hospital/templates/header.html
How to include a template ?

It is not a full path, but relative to the DIRS [Django-doc] and templates/ directory in the apps, if you enable APP_DIRS [Django-doc], so likely:
{% include "header.html" %}
